# change data.frame structure

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

I have two MySQL-tables. One of them contains data of crime cases (i.e. case numbers, locations), the other one contains the crime offences that were commited (i.e. which law was broken, article, paragraph) for each case in the table "cases". Therefore I have a 1:n-relationship with each crime case having multiple offences. Now, I'd like to join both tables, but have no clue how to do this best.

```
table "cases"
ID / casenumber / ...
---------------------
1 / 2015-33323 
2 / 2016-33213
3 / 2017-88873


table "offences"
ID / caseId / law  / article / ...
---------------------
1 / 1       / law1 / 110     / ...
2 / 1       / law1 / 111     / ...
3 / 1       / law2 / 239     / ...
4 / 2       / law1 / 342     / ...
5 / 2       / law3 / 920     / ...
6 / 3       / law1 / 820     / ...
```

In order to join both data.frames I should get the offences-table into a form like that:

```
caseId / offence1law / offence1art / offence2law / offence2art / ...
---------------------
1      / law1        / 110         / law1        / 111 / ...
2      / law1        / 342         / law3        / 920 / ...
3      / law3        / 820         / NA          / NA  / ...
```

Does anyone know how to to do this? the number of variables in the table I am looking for depends on the number of offences committed.

Thank you very much for your hints!

Comment: Your result doesn't use your first table at all; it's just a wider form of your second one. While you could create it with tidyr, my best advice is not to do so, as it's an untidy and less-useful data structure with variables hidden in the column names.

Comment: So you wanna join by `caseId`? `dplyr` has joining functions, check `left_join` for instance

Comment: @ Dambo Joining is not the problem here. The problem is, that the "right" table has a different structure than the "left" table.

Comment: @ alistaire Thank your for your answer! I agree, that the table I want to obtain would not be "tidy". But I have no idea how to integrate table "offences" when analysing the cases-table. For example if I want to answer the question in how many percent of the cases there was an offence against law1 (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr` to create the desired offence-table info. `offences5` is the final output.

The idea is to use `gather`, `unite`, and `spread` to create desired wide format table. After that, use `left_join` to combine the data. Notice that the last `select` and `setNames` are selecting and renaming the columns exactly the same as the OP's desired output. However, if the order of columns is not important, these calls are optional.

The solution has nothing to do with the `cases` data frame. However, if the OP wants, it would be easy to conduct a `left_join` if `offences5` is ready.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

offences2 <- offences %>%
  group_by(caseId) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n(), Law = "law", Art = "art") %>%
  unite(Law2, ID, Law, remove = FALSE, sep = "") %>%
  unite(Art2, ID, Art, remove = TRUE, sep = "")

offences3 <- offences2 %>%
  select(caseId, law, Law2) %>%
  spread(Law2, law)

offences4 <- offences2 %>%
  select(caseId, article, Art2) %>%
  spread(Art2, article)

offences5 <- offences3 %>%
  left_join(offences4, by = "caseId") %>%
  select(c("caseId", sapply(1:length(unique(offences$law)), 
                            function(i) paste0(i, c("law", "art"))))) %>%
  setNames(c("caseId", paste0("offence", colnames(.[, -1]))))

offences5
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   caseId [3]
  caseId offence1law offence1art offence2law offence2art offence3law offence3art
   <int>       <chr>       <int>       <chr>       <int>       <chr>       <int>
1      1        law1         110        law1         111        law2         239
2      2        law1         342        law3         920        <NA>          NA
3      3        law1         820        <NA>          NA        <NA>          NA
```

Data:

```
offences <- read.table(text = "ID caseId law article
                       1 1 law1 110
                       2 1 law1 111
                       3 1 law2 239
                       4 2 law1 342
                       5 2 law3 920
                       6 3 law1 820",
                       header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```